# producing dictionary from dictionary and list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

If I have 2 dictionaries:

Total number of stops:

```
dict1: "a": 10, "b": 12 -->length
```

The stop number that having people waiting for the bus:

```
dict2: "a": [2, 2, 4, 7, 10], "b": [8, 4, 3, 2] --> position
```

For example: for route A there are 2 people at stop #2, 1 at stop #4, 1 at stop #7 and one at stop #10.

where I want to create a dictionary shows the total number of people waiting per each stop for each route like this:

```
dict3:{"a" = [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], "b":[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

what show I do?

Comment: Why are both lists length 10 in the desired result? Shouldn't the value for the `"b"` key be 12 elements?

Comment: yes, should be 12. I miss-typed it.

Comment: your question is still too vague for me. Can you please explain what the second dict really mean? How did it affect the third dict exactly?

Comment: I have updated the information for more detailed of the questions. sorry for the previously vague explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter) to get the total count of passengers waiting at each stop from `dict2`, then use a nested dictionary/list comprehension to turn those counts into an array of people waiting at each stop on each route:

```
from collections import Counter

dict1 = { "a": 10, "b": 12 }
dict2 = { "a": [2, 2, 4, 7, 10], "b": [8, 4, 3, 2] }
counts = { k : Counter(v) for k, v in dict2.items() }
dict3 = { k : [ counts[k][i] for i in range(1, dict1[k]+1) ] for k in dict2.keys() }
print(dict3)
```

Output:

```
{
 'a': [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
 'b': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"a": 10, "b": 12}
dict2 = {"a": [2, 2, 4, 7, 10], "b": [8, 4, 3, 2]}
result = {}
for k,v in dict1.items():
    result[k] = [0] * v
for k,vs in dict2.items():
    for v in vs:
        result[k][v-1] += 1
print(result)
```

Result:

> {'a': [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 'b': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
> 0, 0, 0]}